# How can I access variable from javascript file insize script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to access my variable inside test.js from  tag, how can I do that?

am getting the Uncaught ReferenceError: test (function) is not defined error.

Following is the simplest of functions that I could create in order to isolate the issue.

in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            test();
            alert(a);
        });
</script>
```

main.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function test() {
        console.log("test");
    };
    var a = 100;
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No need to wait for the document to load to create function....

Comment: `var a` is scoped to the function in the document ready.  It will not be available in the other scope, unless you raise it's scope.

Comment: In main.js just write `var a = 100`. The variable will be global. Not recommended, but it's for learning purpose.

Comment: Actually this code also has an issue that `test` is also not in the global scope.

Comment: @Taplar if I remove jQuery(document).ready(function($) { }); from main.js, Is it work?

Comment: That would change the scope of where the function and variable live.